# why i cant deploy my application angular 12 in github pages?

Tags: angular, github, github-pages

I finished my `angular` application, and now I want to deploy it in `github page`, I run the following cmd:

1. `$npm i -g angular-cli-ghpages to install githup page`.
2. `$ng build --prod --base-href="https://najib132.githup.io/appangular/"`
3. I created an appangular repository.
4. `$git remote add origin https://github.com/najib132/appangular.git`
5. `$git push origin master`
6. `$ngh`

and when I enter on [link](https://najib132.github.io/appangular) it gives me `404 file not found`

Comment: You need to set 404 page of github pages as index.HTML

Comment: @GRD can u explain more coz im begining in githup

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli-ghpages